# Rails-4 carrierwave not saving uploaded file via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, ember.js, carrierwave

I am trying to use ajax upload to upload a file using Rails  carrierwave gem.

In the Rails model if I comment out carrierwave uploader the image will load

```
   class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
     #mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader                              
   end
```

Here is the upload saving when carrierwave is commented out above

```
   Processing by Api::AssetsController#create as JSON
   Parameters: {"asset"=>{"attachment"=>"C:\\fakepath\\wiz.jpg"}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "assets" ("attachment", "created_at", "updated_at") 
   VALUES     (?, ?, ?)  [["attachment", "C:\\fakepath\\wiz.jpg"], 
   ["created_at", "2014-11-12 21:19:50.456924"], 
   ["updated_at", "2014-11-12 21:19:50.456924"]]
   (7.8ms)  commit transaction
```

However, when I use carrierwave uploader, the file is correctly passed  in the parameters sent to the controllerr, however, it saves as **nil**

```
     started POST "/api/assets.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-12 13:27:59 +0000
       Processing by Api::AssetsController#create as JSON
       Parameters: {"asset"=>{"attachment"=>"C:\\fakepath\\wiz.jpg"}}
       (0.1ms)  begin transaction
       SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "assets" ("attachment", "created_at", "updated_at")
       VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["attachment", nil],
       ["created_at", "2014-11-12 13:27:59.814416"],    
       ["updated_at", "2014-11-12 13:27:59.814416"]]
       (7.0ms)  commit transaction
```

The request headers has the multipart

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200
Request URL:http://localhost:4200/api/assets.json
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Accept:*/*
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryX8gWNEUkD4hyVsxz
```

The request payload looks like this:

```
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryX8gWNEUkD4hyVsxz
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="asset[attachment]"

   C:\fakepath\wiz.jpg
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryX8gWNEUkD4hyVsxz--
```

The Rails controller

```
    class Api::AssetsController < ApplicationController
       def create
         @asset = Asset.new(asset_params)
         @asset.attachment = params[:asset][:attachment]
         if @asset.save
           render json: @asset, status: :ok
         end
        end

        private

       def asset_params
         params.require(:asset).permit(:attachment)                     
       end
    end
```

Comment: can you add your uploader file and your form along with your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to use HTML-5 form-data to send the form but to use jquery-file-upload plugin. With that change carrierwave could detect the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I found carrierwave more trouble than it was worth with inconsistent model state attributes present from when a file is first uploaded vs retrieving an already uploaded file. The convolution and downright complexity is beyond belief.

I recommend just following the [rails guide on uploading files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files). The rails controller is very simple and you have full control of what you want to do, defer to a queue for background processing ... whatever you want.  Its nice and clean and easy and simple to change as required. Like you I use Ember and ajax to send the file as multipart form-data and it works.

IMO a lot of these gems are more trouble than they're worth as they conflate different concerns and just end up making a mess of it.  I fail to see the value add they provide.

If you want to post process images just use the image processing library of your choice (ruby vips is fast), if you want to process a CSV file just do what you need to. No need for complicated variant handling and matching rubbish which has some nasty ordering edge cases.

If you really must use the carrierwave uploader gem then I'm sorry I probably haven't answered your question but perhaps I've made you consider what real value you think you're getting from it..